# How do I open the user folder of a hard drive that I transfered?

Tags: windows, hard-drive-recovery

My Windows 10 notebook died but fortunately I was able to rescue the hard drive and put it into another PC.

Unfortunately, the other PC can't open the `C/Users/Joe` folder. What do I have to do to open the folder?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to open that folder?

Comment: This will be an ownership issue...

Answer (score 33):

You can gain access to this folder by following these steps to ***take ownership*** and then ***grant yourself full access*** to the folder.

1. Right-click the folder > **Properties**
2. *Security* tab > **Advanced**
3. Click **Change** to the right of *Owner*
4. Enter `Users` into box and click **OK**
5. Enable the checkbox **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects** then click **Apply**
6. If prompted that *You do not have permissions to read...* click **Yes**
7. Completely close out of the *Advanced Security Settings* dialog
8. Right-click the folder > **Properties**
9. *Security* tab > **Edit...**
10. **Add...**
11. Enter `Users` into box and click **OK**
12. Enable the **Full Control** checkbox then click **OK**

Comment: Please mark this post as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: This works, but for me Windows Explorer has always popped up a dialog and asked if I want permanent access to the folder, and then automatically created all the permission changes to make it so.

Comment: Works, thanks!

Note that two of the steps (I believe 5 and 12) may take a long time

Comment: FWIW: If you don't want to change folder hierarchy/ownership AND/OR you're browsing a read-only drive... something that works for me is to spawn a `cmd` prompt as the SYSTEM user, for example using `PsExec64.exe -s -i cmd`. This will allow you to run programs as SYSTEM and read/browse everything that the SYSTEM user can, which in most cases is pretty much everything. An alternative to PSExec is `AdvancedRun.exe` from NirSoft.